# findOne works but not get all/find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

findOne works fine

```
db.collection('updates', function (err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({
            author: req.user._id
        }, function (err, doc) {
        }
 });
```

I'm trying to get all the documents instead of just one. I'm changing findOne to find (shown below) and it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

```
        db.updates.find({
            author: req.user._id
        }, function (err, doc) {
        }
```

The error message:
It's saying Cannot call method "find" of undefined, meaning the collection isn't being recognized.

Update:
This doesn't work either:

```
db.collection('updates', function (err, collection) {
        collection.find({ //changed findOne to find
            author: req.user._id
        }, function (err, doc) {
        }
 });
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". You get no results? You get an error?

Comment: Yeah that comment was removed. But where is the "collection with a period in it?" Don't see one. Only "updates".

Comment: It's saying cannot call method "find" of undefined, meaning it doesn't recognize the collection.

Comment: Umm. `db.collection('updates',function(err,collection) { collection.find(...) })`. Do you think that might be the same since you have two completely different listings to access? You also should have tagged to node.js

Comment: Thanks Neil! I'll tag it now. I tried changing findOne to just find and that's giving the same error. Cannot call method "find" of undefined.

Comment: I'd actually look harder and say "Thanks Neil for pointing out the obvious error". There is no such thing as `db.updates` there is only `db.collection()` and whatever collection you named and passed to the callback. See it now? Your username gives away that this is not really your bag.

Comment: Also if this is the basic Node.js driver then `req.user._id` is bound to fail because it's a string. It needs to be an `ObjectId` in order to work. You need to cast it. So if you think one case works then you have other code you are not showing that is making it work.

Comment: Still not working when I change findOne to find like you suggested. That's the reason for this question. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Interesting. How would I get it to find/get all when findOne works? We'll see if using it as a string works. It might not. It's saying my collection is undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using [Native MongoDB Node.JS Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) to query your database. [According to its readme](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-all-documents), you should use `.toArray()` method to instantiate [MongoDB cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/), returned from `.find()` call:

```
collection.find({
  author: req.user._id
}).toArray(function (err, docs) {
  // docs is an Array of documents here
});
```

If you have troubles with Native MongoDB Node.JS Driver, I would suggest using some wrapper around it with more intuitive API, e.g.:

- [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs)
- [monk](https://github.com/Automattic/monk)
- [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin)

Comment: note that as of MongoDB Node.JS driver 4.10 [callbacks are deprecated](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/whats-new/#what-s-new-in-4.10) in favor of promises, so `collection.find().toArray` is all you need now