# .findOne works in data attribute of Iron Router Route but .find does not?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am writing an app with dynamic content loads. I am using Iron Router and am aiming to avoid Sessions if possible. I wrote the following route bellow:

```
Router.route('/:publisher',{
  name: "publisher",
  action: function(){
    this.render("Publisher")
  },
  data: function(){
    return Comics.findOne({publisher: this.params.publisher});
  }
});
```

Which works, as it uses .findOne. If I switch .findOne to .find, nothing loads, but there are no errors. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Note: I looked at this link, but it's sadly not the same problem: [findOne works but not get all/find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823478/findone-works-but-not-get-all-find)

Comment: try using `var finde = Comics.find({publisher: this.params.publisher}).fetch();` and `console.log(finde)`

Comment: This results in multiple arrays, which seems like it's looping through constantly, adding an entry to the array each time. This then displays three different arrays, instead of appending the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collection.find().fetch()` instead of `collection.find()`

`collection.findOne()` is approximately equivalent to `collection.find({},{limit: 1}).fetch()[0]`

**Explanation**

`collection.find()` is a cursor, whereas `collection.find().fetch()` is an array of objects.

Comment: If I console log Comics.find({publisher: this.params.publisher}).fetch(), three arrays are a result. It appears as if it's looping over the collection with those params and creating a new array each time, adding the new find to it.

Comment: Are you rendering the template before the subscription is complete?

Comment: I forgot to add a waitOn. Silly me. Thanks!